# VkDescriptorSet from previous pipeline giving performance warning

Tags: vulkan

Vulkan allowes multiple sets of input description. In my use case I render a specific object with 2 sets. Set 0 with 2 offsets into a dynamic buffer containing frame data and object data on the two different offset locations. Set 1 with a texture to change per object. So after my first pass i have 2 sets bound. Now when i start the next subpass and bind a different pipeline these two sets are still bound, then when i then try to bind set 0 (i do not need set 1 now), i get a performance warning about incompatability.

`DescriptorSetDS 0x10 previously bound as set #0 is incompatible with set 0x668cec8 newly bound as set #0 so set #1 and any subsequent sets were disturbed  by newly bound pipelineLayout (0x64)`

Now this is clear to me, and I understand that set 1 is "disturbed". But what i do not know how to do is to tell vulkan this is correct, so the warning is not given anymore (it seems wrong to design software that always gets this error). I expect something like a reset of the sets that are bound, "unbinding" the sets. But I think I am missing something because I see nothing of the sort.

Of course maybe i'm doing something wrong, or missing some related command, so my simplified call order for completion:

`vkCmdBeginRenderPass
vkCmdBindPipeline
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets -> bind sets: 0, 1
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers
vkCmdDraw
vkCmdNextSubpass
vkCmdBindPipeline (different pipeline)
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets -> bind set: 0 -> error about set disturbance`

Comment: "*it seems wrong to design software that always gets this error*" It's not an error; it's a warning. While it is legitimate in your case, it may catch errors if someone expected it to work. You can probably shut the warning up by binding empty sets to the other set indices.

Comment: I think you can shut it up by changing the last set instead. The layer tries to hint, that the last set should be most changed and the first the least. Or you now, "reset" the state by moving it to different CB.

Comment: How do you only specify usage of set 1 in a pipeline layout? It seems the layouts of the sets are implicitly determined by the order of pSetLayouts in VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo, which always starts at 0. Then you could bind the set 0 from the previous pipelinelayout before the set 1 which you actually care about, but that just seems terrible design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, there's no really good answer to this. What you're doing at present should be perfectly fine performance-wise. It's just that there's no way to adequately communicate your intention to the debug layer.

The Vulkan API doesn't have a way for you to say "I'm setting set 0 and I don't care about any of the later sets." Therefore, the validation layer can't tell the difference between that and "I'm setting set 0 and I want to retain the later sets." The actual driver doesn't care, but the validation layer needs to know your intent.

I would suggest just putting up with the warning. If you try to do something like make it use set 1 or 2, you'd just be making things more difficult for yourself. You'd have to invent a pipeline layout where set 0 is an empty set, but then you have to actually bind an empty set to set 0. Which means you have to create an empty descriptor set to bind there.

It's just a false positive.